# How do I prove that the integral from negative infinty to infinty of $e^{-.5x^2}$ is $\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Tags: normal-distribution

I've tried integration by parts, u-substitution, and a Taylor Series expansion. I feel like the gamma function would play a role in this proof, but I'm not sure how. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral looks like a [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). The answer to your question is $$I = \sqrt{2\pi}$$
More generally, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+b)^2}dx = \sqrt{\frac \pi a}$$
You might want to check out the linked wiki article for a proof/more details.

Comment: Thank you Aniruddha. That article helped me figure out the proof.